# Парсить в Сервлете

Tags: java, html, парсер, servlet, jsoup

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Написал сервлет и хочу, чтобы в нём парсился сайт и выаскивалось одно значение. Когда запуская приложение, то оно не останавливается и выводит только ошибку.

```
Трейс:
    D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\bin\catalina.bat run
    [2017-10-19 06:21:08,397] Artifact mySite3:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Aydar\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_82_mySite3"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Sep 29 2017 12:23:15 UTC
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.82.0
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            10.0
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Aydar\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_82_mySite3
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Aydar\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_82_mySite3\conf\logging.properties
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\endorsed
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Aydar\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_82_mySite3
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\temp
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Aydar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Aydar\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 591 ms
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 77 ms
    Connected to server
    [2017-10-19 06:21:09,486] Artifact mySite3:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
    WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1899)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/nodes/Element
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:891)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5519)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        ... 56 more

    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
    SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1019)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1899)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    окт 19, 2017 6:21:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
    SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:309)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1019)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1899)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        ... 33 more

    [2017-10-19 06:21:09,897] Artifact mySite3:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\manager
    окт 19, 2017 6:21:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\webapps\manager has finished in 217 ms


Страница с ошибкой:
HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    myServlet1.doPost(myServlet1.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    myServlet1.doPost(myServlet1.java:20)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, как это исправить или чем можно заменить эту реализацию

```
Сервлет:
@WebServlet(name = "myServlet1", urlPatterns = "/myServlet1")
public class myServlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //получение города, для вставки в адрес сайта.
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        //получение HTML
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/"+city).get();
        //получение того поля, что мне и нужно (значение температуры)
        Elements divElements = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "temp fact__temp");
        divElements.forEach(divElement ->{
            text = divElement.child(0).text();
    });
        out.write(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `появляются ошибки` — какие?

Comment: Ссылается на строчки кода, где сервлет обращается к классу tt, и в классе tt где происходит connection. Эта ошибка возникает при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" на странице, с которой начинает работу сервлет, и описывает на новой странице, куда он меня перекидывает. Ошибка 500

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть полный текст ошибки, стактрейс, и не в комментариях, а в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Исправьте код в смысле правил именования классов и переменных - его очень сложно читать - ничего не понятно. Также непонятно зачем вы конструктор со статическими методами и полями мешаете. Это странно и неправильно. И да - подробности ошибки в вопросе приведите.

Comment: Переписал код, добавил комментарии и избавился от класса. Ошибку тоже указал в вопросе. 
Извините за неудобный код

Comment: на метод сервлета попадает? делали точку останова?

Comment: не хотите с помощью spring boot переделать ваш проект меньше геммороя с сервлетом будет?

Comment: Я только начинаю, поэтому и написал через "вот так".
и да, сервлет начинает работу, но выскакивает вот тут
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/"+city).get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было засунуть библиотеку из org/jsoup/Jsoup, на которую ругалась страница, в папку WEB-INF. Теперь всё работает))